# How to Move Android layout's background loop

Tags: android, layout, background, jquery-animate

I am new in android.
I am try to animate layout background.
is it possible to move the background till i click on pause button? 
Please Help me....!

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar) Tutorial. In this background image is moving i-e animation.Hope this may help you out. you just have to add functionality of Pause.